# How to split a string into array of six character?

Tags: string, python-3.x, numpy, split

I have a string that is :

```
doc = 'a3fprma3j4kfa3bedv'
```

And I want to create an array:

```
['a3fprm', 'a3j4kf', 'a3bedv']
```

Every six character to be a string in an array 
When I try :

```
rer = [doc[i] for i in range(len(doc))]
god = []
for i in range(0, len(doc) - 6 + 1):
    god.append(doc[i:i +6])
```

The result isn't the one I want
How do I code for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below. The only thing is the string has to be a multiple of 6 to display a value in the list. For example if you add 5 more characters to the string the output would be the same as the last 5 characters would be ignored.

The difference from your code is the addition of a third parameter in the `range()` function, `range(6, len(doc) + 1, 6)`. This third parameter tells the for loop to step through the string in intervals of 6.

```
doc = 'a3fprma3j4kfa3bedv'

docArr = []

for i in range(6, len(doc) + 1, 6):
    docArr.append(doc[i-6:i])

print(docArr)
```

Output:

```
['a3fprm', 'a3j4kf', 'a3bedv']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `range(0, len(doc), 6)` to generate the sequence (with a step of 6):

```
[doc[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(doc), 6)]
# ['a3fprm', 'a3j4kf', 'a3bedv']
```